# How to efficiently search an element in a TreeSet without using contains?

Tags: java, performance, search, tree, iteration

I'm quite new to Java and its libraries so its possible this question comes as a dumb or obvious one.
Assuming I have a class like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private double salary;

    // Assume the usual gets, sets, deep clone and etc.

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(this == o)
            return true;
        if(o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Person p = (Person) o;
        return ((this.name.equals(p.getName()))
            && (this.code.equals(p.getCode()))
            && (this.salary == p.getSalary()));
    }

    public int compareTo(Person p)
    {
        return this.code.compareTo(p.getCode());
    }

    public static Comparator<Person> PersonCodeComparator = new Comparator<Person>()
    {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
        {
            String s1 = p1.getCode();
            String s2 = p2.getCode();
            
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    };
}
```

And that in another class or main function I'm using it in a:
`TreeSet<Person> peopleSet = new TreeSet<>(Person.PersonCodeComparator);`

So far I understood that TreeSet add, contains and etc are built to be efficient when traversing the TreeSet. But when I'm trying to make the methods to find if a person exists on the TreeSet and to get that person's file based on a code or name, I'm pretty sure it's not using the binary search that a tree should allow for example.

Instead of this:

```
public boolean existsPerson(String code)
{
    for(Person p : peopleSet) {
        if(code.equals(p.getCode())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public Employee getPerson(String code)
{
    for(Employee p : peopleSet) {
        if(e.getCode().equals(code)) {
            return e.clone();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

which makes me think its basically a linear search on a ordered set, is there maybe a way to redo these that utilizes the benefits of it actually being a Tree and not just like an ordered array? There must be, otherwise I'm confused what else the Comparator and Comparable classes are needed then besides sorting.
I searched several other questions and didn't found a reply that match my question. I also am not looking for replies that require using other ways to store, since I'm trying to learn/understand more about Sets and TreeSet.

---

Thank you @louis-wasserman and @bohemian for the comments.
For the existPerson I'll use the contains function, since seems to use compare or compareTo.
As for the part of getting the object in the TreeSet, I'll create a "fake" person with the code I want to search for, `Person pt = new Person(code,"",0.0)` and use either:

`peopleSet.subSet(pt,true,pt,true).first()`

or

`peopleSet.tailSet(pt).first()`

That I assume will work as long as the sets are in ascending order of whatever value I use to search.

Comment: Why use a TreeSet? Use a HashMap, which is faster and easier to use.

Comment: I know that, and as I mentioned in my question: 'I also am not looking for replies that require using other ways to store, since I'm trying to learn/understand more about Sets and TreeSet'. Like those there's a bunch of them.

Comment: TreeSet doesn't use a linear search, it uses a binary tree search, so all operations are O(log n). HashSet is O(1). btw, a comment is not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I passed the HashMaps / HashSets part. Just the TreeSet that bugs me that is a "tree" but I couldn't even find a way to use comparators or comparable to search elements more efficiently, to use the contains or the get from it, it requires me to make a "bad" equals, that would only compare the code, for example.

Comment: TreeSet is not as efficient as HashSet. There's just no way around it. It's actually a tree.

Comment: If your search criteria is the `code` property, just use a `Map` from code to `Person`. It can be a `TreeMap` or `HashMap`, whatever you like. Besides that, there is no sense in making a class `Comparable` and create a `Comparator` implementing exactly the same logic at the same time. Since persons have no natural order (as there can be different equally valid properties you can use for sorting), the preferred approach is to only use `Comparator`s and don’t implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3):

> is there maybe a way to redo these that utilizes the benefits of it actually being a Tree and not just like an ordered array

No.  The `TreeSet` API only allows you to do efficient lookups with a `Person` object, not just the property being compared.  You could construct a "fake" `Person` object to do the job, and you could *maybe* force it to do `getPerson` by calling `ceiling` or the like to get out an element, but that's certainly not how `TreeSet` is designed to be used.

> since I'm trying to learn/understand more about Sets and TreeSet

Part of learning about Sets and TreeSet is learning about the use cases they are not designed for.  They are not designed for this.

Comment: Well, I assumed that much could be a possibility.
I also had that idea of creating that fake Person idea, and use contains at least for the first one, but contains uses equals to validate (according to the API) but in this case wouldn't work since in the equals I'm comparing all the elements, not only the code,

Comment: Read the docs on `TreeSet` again: "a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface."  `TreeSet.contains` does _not_ use `equals`.

Comment: Could I get that reference? I did read the API. And according to [Oracles Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) it says: 'Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).'
But you are right, I tested differently and contains does return true even when I create a different person with only the same code. My bad, I was tricked by the API description

Comment: The quote is just from the top of that page.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I skimmed over it. I think the documentation was tricky for this one.
But, just checked. I think, they use equals for the adding new elements part. (I managed to add 2 people with different names but same nif in it) but both the subSet, tailSet, headSet and contains must be using the compareTo or compare from Comparator instead. (Later I'm gonna try check that between compare and compareTo).
In any case, thank you for the comments.

Comment: @Pirata in what way does the fact that you added 2 people with different names but same nif in it prove your theory that `add` uses `equals`? These two object are different, whether you check with `equals` or `compareTo`.